# How to upgrade Win32 C + MASM "solution" from Visual Studio 2015 to VS 2017/2019

Tags: winapi, configuration, visual-studio-2017, masm32

Summary:  A VS2015 solution with mixed C and Assembler, does not display symbols in assembler code when debugging after upgrading to VS2017 or VS2019).
[Oct 2109: problem solved, see note at end].

Long details:

I have a VS 2015 xxx.sln with 32 bit C code compiled by the VS 2015 compiler, with a large 32 bit assembler code parlanse0.asm assembled by a custom command line:

parlanse0.asm Property Pages

```
Item Type:   Custom Build Tool

Command Line: ml /D SANITYCHECKS="1" /D EVENTBUFFERENABLE="1" /D TESTING="1" /D PROFILE="0"  /Sg /Sl132 /Sx /Zd /Zi /c /Cx /coff /Zd /Fl "%(FullPath)"
Outputs: parlanse0.obj;%(Outputs)
Additional Dependencies:  <list of MASM include file>
Link Objects:  Yes
Treat Output As Content: No
```

I'm not sure this is relevant, but here's the Linker options:

```
/OUT:"Debug\run.exe" /MANIFEST /PROFILE /NXCOMPAT:NO /PDB:"Debug/erun.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE:NO "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "netapi32.lib" "iphlpapi.lib" "psapi.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" /LARGEADDRESSAWARE /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH:NO /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:".\Debug\run.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE",5.01" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:".\Debug\run.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MAP":.\Debug/run.map" /ORDER:@"RTSCFunctionOrder.txt" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Lib" /DELAYLOAD:"iphlpapi.dll" /DELAYLOAD:"comdlg32.dll" /TLBID:1
```

[If this is the linker command line, where does it get the names of the .obj files it processes?]

This solution compiles/builds/runs fine under VS 2015.

I'm trying to upgrade to VS 2017 (update: Sept 2019, problem never resolved, so  I just tried it again with VS 2019... same problem).

The upgrade seemed trivial: I simply started VS 2017 and pointed it at the VS 2015 solution file.   Apparently
nothing changes, at least my source control (over the various MS build files like .sln don't see any changes).   Magically, almost everything works: I can compile/run/debug the application.

However, the assembly source code is no longer visible when I'm in the debugger and attempt to "go to source code" when I've stepped into a bit of assembler.   "Goto source code" from the assembler works fine in VS 2015.  Likewise, if during debugging I choose an assmbley language source line and attempt to "Go to disassembly" I get a pop-up window "Disassembly cannot be displayed... there is no executable code associated with this location", and that's clearly wrong.  Also behavior that was find under VS 2015.

What do I have to change?  Are there documents somewhere that describe what is different?

[Addition:  The assembler source is in a different directory than the .C sources.  This causes the .sbr file for the assembler code to be produced in a different directory from the .sbr files for the C code.   Apparently the assembler code .sbr is not picked up the build process; in one of the log files I can see all the .sbr files for the C code but not for the assembler.
So this doesn't look right. However, my understanding is .sbr files support VisualStudio tag lookup, not object-location-to-source-line map so I think this is a red herring.   Where is the object-location-to-source-line map produced?  Does the linker do it?]

[Addition: following the advice in the comments to look at another answer, I changed the /DEBUG option to /DEBUG:FULL with no apparent effect on the problem.]

[I found some article on PDB files, and how the C++ compiler "updates" it as is compiles individual .cpp (.c?) files.  Is MASM supposed to generate a PDB files?   So... how would MASM update the compiler's target PDB file?]

... added after 2 month delay ...

I see this in a disassembly window on *my* assembler code:

```
00480107 CC                   int         3  
00480108 CC                   int         3  
RTSAllocate11D_end:
00480109 8D A4 24 00 00 00 00 lea         esp,[esp]  
00480110 8D A4 24 00 00 00 00 lea         esp,[esp]  
00480117 8D A4 24 00 00 00 00 lea         esp,[esp]  
0048011E 8D A4 24 00 00 00 00 lea         esp,[esp]  
00480125 8D A4 24 00 00 00 00 lea         esp,[esp]  
0048012C 8D A4 24 00 00 00 00 lea         esp,[esp]  
00480133 8D A4 24 00 00 00 00 lea         esp,[esp]  
0048013A 8D 9B 00 00 00 00    lea         ebx,[ebx]  
allocate_2to1E_bytes:
```

These are *my* symbols, so they are clearly getting to the debugger.  I ask the disassembly window to show line numbers...  it does nothing.   So somehow the symbols are getting through, but not the line number information or maybe not the source file location.  Thoughts?

EDIT:  October 9, 2019:  **PROBLEM CLAIMED SOLVED.** A long interaction with Microsoft got them to agree this is a problem in the debugger.   I verified that VS 2015 Update 1 was the last version that worked properly; VS 2015 Update 2 and later, VS 2017 and VS 2019 all suffer from the same problem.    MS has told me that they have identified the problem and a fix will be available in VS 2019 v16.4 Public Release in December 2019.

Comment: Possible the file is the same place you'll find the missing socks and airline luggage?

Comment: could it be related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842328/symenumsymbols-returns-error-success-but-gives-no-results/

Comment: @SimonMourier:  Can you explain how? Your referenced Q/A is about an application dynamically loading symbols.  What's that got do with finding source code?

Comment: Isn't "go to source code" about finding symbols? How PDB are generated has changed for 2017. Check Hans' answer

Comment: might help : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b418fbfe-9013-4eda-ad53-c02ce96e67ed/what-component-in-visual-studio-2017-do-i-need-to-install-to-get-masm-support-thats-all-i-want?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: if */Zd* option exist in command line  for ml[64] - must be debug info in obj file. the *pdb* build *link.exe* - look in custom build step - what exactly command line set for your asm file. usually need use `ml[64] /c /Cp /Zd $(InputFileName)` + possible some */D* macros

Comment: @RbMm:  I've provided the command line I used for the assembler in the body of the question.  It includes /Zd and /c.   /Cp seems to be about preserving identifier case...  the complaint from the IDE is "There is no source associated with this location" so the problem isn't case sensitivity.

Comment: @MichaelPetch:  I'm sorry, I'm not smart enough to understand your comment and desperate enough to ask you for more detail if you have it.   "The file" refers to ...?   The assembler source file is fine, it assembles, builds, links, runs.  Just no symbols in the debugger.

Comment: My comment was sarcasm and not meant to be useful at all.

Comment: @IraBaxter - you can how minimum look in `parlanse0.obj` - are source asm file name is present in it. if no - really no debug info in obj. if yes - debug info exist.

Comment: @RbMm: Good suggestion.  I looked in parlanse0.obj in emacs.  Lots of source file names and labels: e.g.  C:\DMS\Domains\PARLANSE\Tools\RuntimeSystem\Source\PARLANSE0.asm (yes, that's the path to the main file) and RunReadyGranuleFound (yes, that's one of the labels).  So the debug information seems to exist.   is the linker somehow losing this stuff?

Comment: @IraBaxter - if this names exist - linker must include it in result pdb if you build with debug info enabled. how minimum this say that with *ml* command line all ok and problem not here..

Comment: @RbMm:  OK, so I looked in "erun.pdb" with emacs.   Yes, I can see the file path "C:\...\PARLANS0.asm"  and I can see symbols I expect from the assembler code.  This means the PDB file is OK.  So ... why don't I see symbols in the debugger?  Going to "PARLANSE0.ASM" tab in VS2017 IDE, goto to source line, click on "show disassembly" gets me "Disassembly cannot be displayed for source location ... no executable code at this location..."

Comment: @IraBaxter - hard to say - i be try windbg - are he can go to src ? if yes - problem in vs 2017 debugger

Comment: @RbMm:  I'm not sure I'm going to get an answer before bounty runs out.  You've been the most helpful of the lot; please post your comments as and answer and I'll award the  bounty to you so it doesn't get wasted.

Comment: @RbMm:  back from hiatus, problem not solved yet.   So why is this a problem with *symbols*?   I'd expect the issue to be a mapping from assembly langauge source lines to object code, that is some kind of line number mapping.   We've had no discussion about this...  where is a source line map to object code constructed/passed to linker/to debugger?  Have .sbr files got something to do with this? All my c code generates .sbr files; the assmbler step does not generate a .sbr file.  Surely I can't be the only guy on the planet with this problem....

Comment: @RbMm:  Add /FR to ml command line; now generates .sbr file.  But how does the .sbr file get processed by the link command (if it does?)  Note this .sbr file is not in same directly as all the rest of the C .obj and .sbr files; never was in the past that that never gave a problem.    I have /Zd ("line number") enabled too... docs claim they are "put in the object file" but it is unclear to me if this is .sbr or .obj.

Comment: @IraBaxter - we not need *.sbr* files at all for debug info. all debug info generated by compiler in .obj file. and finally linker get this info and put to *pdb* file. in *pdb* can exist paths of source files and it map lines-rvas in [`CV_DebugSLinesHeader_t`](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb/blob/master/include/cvinfo.h#L4601) - are you try debug in windbg ? also no show src ? are you try create simply project for test - say small demo asm file ? also can you send in public your pdb file ? I can analyze it and set exactly which info it containing

Comment: so now questions is next:
1) you can not debug asm src only in msvc or in any another debugger, say windbg ?
2) you can not debug asm src only for this project, or if you create test, tiny project with some asm code - you can debug it ?
3) can you send me your *.pdb* file ? if you fail on step 2 - pdb,exe and src for this test

Comment: about symbols and src info - this is independent information - symbols containing in `PDB_STREAM_TPI` stream, symbol lines in another.. say in system pdb files - symbol information exist, but src/lines info usual no. but need look for concrete pdb (I have code for parse it) for say exactly

Comment: OK, I'll try the windbg experiment; no experience so I don't know how long it will take me to fumble through it.  Happy to send the .pdb file to how... how?  Can easily ship to your email address (mine is idbaxter@semdesigns.com if you want to introduce yourself to me offline).

Comment: you can upload your pdb [here](https://www.sendspace.com/) for example and paste me link. or i can build small util which dump context of pdb (modules,files, lines) on your machine (this take 2-3 hours) really this problem need not more that several hours for research and fix, in interactive mode

Comment: i send you 2 mail with analysis of your pdb.

Comment: For others, the analysis by RbMm was that the generated PDB file had all the appropriate data in it.

Comment: @IraBaxter - are you still interesting in resolve problem ? if yes i need again look for parlanse0.obj and pdb (from exe or dll where this parlanse0.obj used). and if can - 2 version - from 2019 build where you can not debug source code, and from 2015 - were you can. and be nice if you have test machine to where you give access via teamviwer for fast look exe + src under debugger

Comment: @RbMm: Yes, interested.  I think I have Microsoft's attention, so let me pursue that first.   Give that about a week and then I'll be back with a resolution or we can go ahead.

Comment: can you until send me  parlanse0.obj and pdb again ? this not interfere. i, as debugger writer, also interesting in this. i fix some error in debugger, after view your pdb and now i think my debugger can debug with source your pe. because this ask also - are you can test this with me on some test comp. however - simply obj+pdb also be good now

Comment: @RbMM: Sure.  Working on this now...

Comment: your pdb file is ok. no any bugs here. your masm settings is ok. but exist bug in 17/19 studio debugger. you can not fix this yourself

Comment: @RbMm:  Sorry to hear that :-{   Let's see if MS's attention might help. FWIW, VS2019 seems to build a perfectly fine object file.  Just can't debug there.

Comment: @IraBaxter - you can debug in vs2015 as i showed you in letter - compile and build in vs2019 and debug in 2015. however vs teem need some patch for this

Comment: *FWIW, VS2019 seems to build a perfectly fine object file.* - object files is build by *ml[64].exe* (masm compiler), *cl.exe*, *exe* and *pdb* build by *link.exe* exe - all this tools not depend from VS. and here all ok. but debugger - already component of VS. and in VS2017/19 something broken. from another case even debugger from VS2005 - understand *pdb* generated by 2019 linker

Comment: @RbMm:  Sorry to be sloppy,  VS2019 (and its elements) seems to build fine object and exe files.  If I can get debugger problem solved, I'll be a happy IDE user.

Comment: i understand where vs2019 exactly fail - if code was **outside** *proc / endp* block. 
for functions inside *proc / endp* block it show source code, bat for other code no.

Comment: All: Microsoft appears to acknowledge they have a bug.  Not sure if they understand RbMm's specific complaint.

Answer (score 2):

for have debugging info (in *pdb* file) need 2 steps:

- compiler must include debugging information to obj file for ml[64]
  compiler this is [/Zd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0ksfwcf.aspx) option
- linker must have [/DEBUG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/xe4t6fc1(v=vs.80).aspx) option in command line. in this case it
  get debug info (stored in `.debug$S` sections of *obj / lib* files) and
  create *pdb* file

if command line both for compiler and linker correct (have this options) need check in following order:

1. look in *.obj* file in any text/binary viewer - are full path string
   of sourse asm file name exist in file. simply search for
   `PARLANSE0.ASM` (or how your source file named) in file as is (all
   names stored as ansi plain text) - are this name is found are path
   is correct ? if yes - this mean with compiler (ml in our case all
   correct and we can go forward)
2. look in *pdb* file - are this strings exist here also ?
3. look in *exe* file - search for `.pdb` - are full (and correct) path
   for your *pdb* exist in *exe* file ? again it stored as plain ansi
   text
4. try alternative debugger use - i be suggest [windbg](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/download-windbg) - are he can
   go to source. for easy check you even can make special temporary
   build - set breakpoint before go to asm code (or direct in some asm
   procedure) and call this procedure at very begin of *exe*. even if
   this "incorrect" by logic - we need only check - are debugger
   understand *pdb* format and can show source for asm

if *windbg* can go to asm source code - this mean some problem with integrated vs2017 debugger. if *windbg* can not - some problems with *pdb* format generated

Comment: ... I never resolved this problem.   Now have VS 2019 installed.  Exactly the same behavior.

Comment: .. found this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/95867/fatal-error-lnk1103-debugging-information-corrupt.html   IIRC, you said my PDB file seemed just fine... but you had a bug in *your* PDB file decoder.   MS claims to have changed the obj file format.     Did you bug have something to do with file format change?

Comment: @IraBaxter - sent to you email. i not think that debug format is changed (my test not confirm this). i need again look for *parlanse0.obj* and *pdb* (from exe or dll where this *parlanse0.obj* used). and if can - 2 version - from 2019 build where you can not debug src code, and from 2015 - were you can

Answer (score 1):

Change the assembly file name `P.asm` to `parlanse0.asm` 
or Add `/Fo parlanse0.obj` to the beginning of your custom build script.

You cannot generate `parlanse0.obj` and debug related files(`parlanse0.iobj`, `parlanse0.ipdb`) via yours. However, you may build without any problems since the files were compiled before.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Sorry to confuse.  The actual name *is* parlanse0.asm; I changed it to P.asm to simplify my question and wasn't consistent, creating a red herring.  I've changed all references to say parlanse0 properly.   ...

Comment: ... ignoring that gaffe, ... what are ".iobj" and ".ipdb" files?  Why do I need them?  How to do (not?) produce them "via yours"?  I change the assembler code all the time, I can't count on a long-ago "compiled before" version.